# regex password validation

Tags: java, regex

How would I get this so it would check for 2 or more digits in the String?  Invoking matches on the String s.

```
s.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$");
```

Comment: To check for a digit in Java, you have to use `\p{Nd}`. If you just want `[0-9]`, that’s different of course.

Comment: Do you have some sample input?

Comment: @tchrist I find it entertaining that you correct this error in almost every regex question :) (not complaining -- I didn't realise the difference before you noted it)

Comment: @Tim what's the difference btw?

Comment: @OscarRyz \p{Nd} contains another [410 characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), including the Soviet U+0968 (२).

Comment: BTW,  is there a sample input? I think I have the correct answer, but I might be overloooking something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023599/regex-password-validation/5023774#5023774

Answer (score 8):

This should do it...

```
^(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$
```

The only change I made is adding this `(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])` which is a positive lookahead that will try to find the first 2 digits within the password.  If it's satisfied, then the regular expression will proceed as usual.

Now, I just thought I'd point out that your regular expression will disallow special characters (punctuation and such).  In practice, some people like to enter weird characters like this in their passwords.

So you might consider something more like this...

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}$
```

This will allow special characters while also ensuring at least one capital letter, one lower case letter, and one number exist in the password.  This is just an example of a strong password regular expression I wrote awhile back, and you could certainly relax those restrictions a bit if you so desired.

Comment: +1: It's just amazing how complicated this doesn't have to be!

Answer (score 1):

Match it twice:

```
s.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$");
s.matches("[0-9].*[0-9]");
```

Use the results like this:

```
if ( s.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$") && s.matches("[0-9].*[0-9]") ) {
    # password is valid
}
```

Comment: Does not work.  return s.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$") && s.matches("[0-9].*[0.9]");   returns false for "2aaaaa2".  It should check if theres 2 or more digits aswell as minimum 8 length string.

Comment: What does not work? You will have to use the return values for those two statements.

Comment: I did this  public static boolean isValidPassword(String s) {
  
  return s.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$") && s.matches("[0-9].*[0.9]");   printing false for this System.out.println(isValidPassword("2aaaaa2"));

  
 }

Comment: I don't know Java regexes that well, but is `*` greedy? Would you have to add a `?` so it doesn't consume the second digit?

Comment: @unleashed: The first one checks for the minimum length. It returns false for "2aaaaa2" because it contains 7 characters, and 7<8.

Comment: You have a typo in the second regex :) And why not `[0-9]{2,}`?

Comment: @EboMike: No need to do that, since the `*` backtracks until it matches if it can match.

Comment: @unleashed Your password is only 7 characters long, so I wouldn't expect any other result than `false`. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Skurmedel: Thanks, I missed the dash :) [0-9]{2,} would not work, as it would only find two _neighboring_ digits. It would not pass "2a2".

Comment: Right, i'm passing "2aaaaaaaa2" and used ur suggestions and still returning false.  It's been giving me a headache for a while.

Comment: Am I missing something? Doesn't the 2nd match anything starting and ending with a digit? Doesn't this fail for a00a?  How about `.*[0-9].*[0.9].*`?

Comment: @Tim Nordenfur: You are absolutely right. It's getting late hehe.  @spintheblack: Nah, since it is unbounded it will match any two digits with zero or more characters between them.

Comment: @unleashed Did you correct my mistake that Skurmedel pointed out? The last `.` should be a `-`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @spintheblack: No. The `^` and `$` metacharacters are used to match start and end of a string. The second regex lacks them.

Comment: Right, i'm using the above "[0-9].*[0-9]" and "as22aaaaaa" does not work.

Comment: @unleashed  Hello!!!... sample input please? I have tried my answer with several ones ( including 2aaaaa2 and ins working fine!!!

Comment: @OscarRyz: Yeah, even with all the things stated as tried by him, all the solutions given work with any Regex engine I have. Yours and this, and Joe's. Something else must be afoot.

Comment: @Skurmedel Java's regex implementation is slightly different because the match method doesn't consume all the input. So `\d.*\d` doesn't "matches" `a2aa2a` ( returns false ) but using `find()` does work.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see any good reason to check the length of a string with a regex - keep it simple is always a good idea, but especially with regexes the temptation to throw everything into a completely unreadable string (that may have some strange edgecases) is pretty tempting.

Just use the length method for the length and something like "\w*?\d\w*?\d\w*"
Note that .* is greedy so don't forget the ? after it. \d signifies a digit in java - I don't think there are any cases with unicode you'd miss with [0-9] - but better safe than sorry

Edited to use \w instead of .  (only word characters i.e. [a-zA-Z_0-9])

Comment: That regex does not find if the string contains only alphanumeric characters and at least two digits? Agree with you on length check, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`(?:^|\s+)(\w{8,})(?<=(.*\d.*\d.*))(?:\s+|$)`

Modified to allow for more than 8 chars from:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/regexp/thread/8e0ced1f-8ddc-4583-89de-e29b4c4dc726

Comment: +1 @Tim, i was going to mention that in the answer but didn't want to sound like a n00b. Now the answer looks hardcore!! yeah! (as long as it works)

Comment: "Hardcore" isn't the word I would use. :D  And no, it doesn't work.  .NET is one of only two regex flavors that support unbounded variable-length lookbehind, and the other one is not Java; that check should be done in a **lookahead**.  And why would you check for even *one* whitespace character at either end, much less one *or more*?  Even the anchors aren't necessary in this case, because the OP is using the `matches()` method, which implicitly anchors the match at both ends.

Answer (score 1):

**edit**

Don't use `match`, but `find`. ( read [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) )

> *The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.*>

That's why `\d.*\d` doesn't work with `a2a2a`

> *The find method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.*

This is what you need.

You just have to test if there is are two numbers with anything in between `\d.*\d` :

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class TwoDigits { 
    public static void main( String ... args ) { 
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d.*\\d");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( args[0]  );  
        System.out.println("Matched ( found ) ? = " + matcher.find());
    }
}
```

But perhaps I'm missing something here, why don't your try it and tell us where it fails.

```
C:\java>java TwoDigits ""
Matched ( found ) ? = false

C:\java>java TwoDigits "a"
Matched ( found ) ? = false

C:\java>java TwoDigits "1a1"
Matched ( found ) ? = true

C:\java>java TwoDigits "1a"
Matched ( found ) ? = false

C:\java>java TwoDigits "a1a"
Matched ( found ) ? = false

C:\java>java TwoDigits "a1a1"
Matched ( found ) ? = true

C:\java>java TwoDigits "2a2"
Matched ( found ) ? = true

C:\java>java TwoDigits "2aaa2"
Matched ( found ) ? = true

C:\java>java TwoDigits "2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2"
Matched ( found ) ? = true

C:\java>java TwoDigits "2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
Matched ( found ) ? = false

C:\java>java TwoDigits "2aaaaaa2aaaaaaaaaa"
Matched ( found ) ? = true

C:\java>java TwoDigits "a3aaaaa2aaaaaaaaaa"
Matched ( found ) ? = true
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
private Pattern p1  = Pattern.compile("^\\w{8,}$");
private Pattern p2  = Pattern.compile("\\d+(.*)?\\d+");

private boolean match(String s) {
    return p1.matcher(s).find() && p2.matcher(s).find();
}

@Test
public void testPassword() {
    assertTrue("length at least 8", match("2aaaaaa2"));
    assertTrue("length at least 8", match("aaaaaaa22"));
    assertTrue("length at least 8", match("22aaaaaaa"));
    assertTrue("length at least 8", match("aa2aa2aaa"));

    assertFalse("length less than 8", match("2aa2aaa"));
    assertFalse("one digit", match("aa2aaaaa"));
    assertFalse("no digits", match("aaaaaaaa"));
}
```

Comment: `(.*)?`?  You're cruisin' for a Resonance Cascade Scenario there, dude.  Er, I mean catastrophic backtracking, of course! (http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)